# image download in python

Tags: python, image

Hi I have a file called  image.txt which contain around 5,00,000 image url.I want to read the url and download the images and save it in a directory.If the images are not downloadable the I want print the exception and resume the downloading for the others.how can i achieve this in a optimized way.

```
import sys
import os
import urllib


def isValidFile(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        print "Path " + path + " doesn't exist! Aborting..."
        exit(1)


def isValidDir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        print "Path " + path + " doesn't exist! Aborting..."
        exit(1)


def normalize(url):
    url = url.split("/")[-1]
    return url.split("\n")[0]

# Execution Starts Here
urls = sys.argv[1]
isValidFile(urls)

out_dir = sys.argv[2]
isValidDir(out_dir)

with open(urls) as url_array:
    for url in url_array:
        urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(out_dir,      normalize(url)))

    print("Images Downloaded")
```

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code? Do you get an error?

Comment: I am incredibly confused with your code, and what you are trying to do. Can you space it and indent it properly (your indentation isn't correct at all, especially in the second half)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure python solution, you could try this:

```
import urllib
import os

def getImage(url, dest):
    with open(dest, 'wb') as fh:
        fh.write(urllib.urlopen(url).read())

for url in urlArray:
    try:
        getImage(url, os.path.basename(url))
    except Exception:
        print "Error downloading {}".format(url)
```

Comment: It is basically an iterable (e.g. a `list`) with the urls you want to download. For example `urlArray = ['http://www.somedomain.com/image1.jpg', 'http://www.anotherdomain.com/image1.jpg']` etc.